# How can I count the number of a special character in a regular expression?

Tags: java, regex

well, I'm a beginner in working with regular expressions , I wanna design a program that its language  contains of just a and b ( I mean I want It accept just words using a and b.)
then It starts counting the number of a, and b in the expression that I enter. 
but don't know which methods are useful in this case...

Comment: Show some attempt even if not working.

Comment: The words you enter will only contain the letters a and/or b?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot count occurances of a character `x` in a string with regular expressions. You can only validate that a fixed number `n` of `x` are present. Make yourself familiar with [regular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_grammar), context free and context sensitive grammars.

You should use a `java.util.Scanner`, tokenize the input and count it.